# Dedup is not working on Splunk

Tags: splunk

Please see picture below. I inserted `dedup` for `job_duration`, but it was not showing in the search result. I only need one result to do visualisation.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There's not enough information in the picture to give you an answer. Looking at the query I'd guess it's breaking at either the spath or where commands - i doubt both of those commands would work on the same field. Run the query up to those points and check the expected fields are present and update your question. Also paste your splunk query as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like job_min is a multi-value field, which are not supported by `dedup`.  Try `... | eval job_min=mvdedup(duration) | ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If `job_min` is in a multivalue field, you should `mvexpand` first

And, instead of `dedup`, try using `stats`

Like this:

```
| mvexpand job_min
| stats count by job_min
| fields - count
```